# Removing Double quotes within double quotes using terminal

Tags: python, linux, terminal, rdf, quotes

I have a large file ~12G (rdf format) where I want to replace double quotes within double quotes. I want to do this using terminal. Any suggestions
Eg

```
term1 attribute "value"value"
```

should get replaced by:

```
term1 attribute "value"
```

Comment: What if you have, let us say `term1 attribute "value"other"thing"`?

Comment: @brandizzi yes it can be a scenario too. I need is to replace the inner double quotes.